# Why am i getting a value of None?

Tags: python

```
import random

import time
def header():
  printNow("The program is starting now, prepare to be slain")
  monsterTest();
def monsterTest():
 for i in range(0,1):
    currentHp = 99;
    printNow("Starting Health is: "+str(currentHp))
    randomHit = random.randint(0,50)
    attack1 = currentHp - randomHit
    printNow("Monster attacks for: "+str(randomHit))
    printNow("Remaining Health is: "+str(currentHp-randomHit))
    battle1 = attack1
    printNow(">>>")
    printNow("Next Attack Incoming!")
    printNow(">>>")
    time.sleep(1.5)
    currentHp = battle1
    printNow("Current Health is: "+str(currentHp))
    attack2 = currentHp - randomHit
    printNow("Monster attacks again for: "+str(attack2))
    battle2 = currentHp - attack2
    printNow("After That we are left with "+str(battle2)+" HP")
 footer();


def footer():
  printNow(">>>")
  printNow("Thank you for using Cidadel's Battle Simulator, this concludes our test...")

printNow(header())
```

---

```
The program is starting now, prepare to be slain
Starting Health is: 99
Monster attacks for: 38
Remaining Health is: 61
>>>
Next Attack Incoming!
>>>
Current Health is: 61
Monster attacks again for: 23
After that we are left with 38 HP
>>>
Thank you for using Citadel's Battle Simulator, this concludes our test...
*None*
>>>
```

why am i getting this none, i think it has to do with my printNow commands but i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong to cause the actual None value.. :/

I attempted to just run it normally but i consistently get the None value as i go up the list commenting out my lines

Comment: What is `printNow()`?

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
printNow(header())
```

The result of `header()` is passed to `printNow` which evidently prints it, as `header()` returns `None`, due to the implicit `return None` at the end of every function.

Replace that with just a call to `header`:

```
header()
```

Comment: thanks a lot :) that really helped.. Right after you said that i was passing header through i did the good 'ol facepalm